# Como extrair o número da semana do mês no R?

Tags: r, data

Estou com dificuldades em extrair o número da semana do mês de uma data específica.

Exemplo:

```
hoje = Sys.Date()
print(hoje)

[1] "2019-02-11"
```

No exemplo da data acima, `hoje` seria a 2ª semana do mês.

Eu sei que:

```
wday() #extrai o dia da semana.
mday() #extrai o dia do mês.
month() #extrai o mês.
```

Mas como posso usar o `R` para extrair de `hoje` a semana do mês?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `lubridate::day` em conjunto com a função `ceiling`:

```
library(lubridate)

hoje<-Sys.Date() # Sys.Date retorna a data de hoje
[1] "2019-02-11"

day(hoje) # day retorna o dia do mês
[1] 11

day(hoje)/7 # dividir o dia pelo número de dias de uma semana (7)
[1] 1.571429

ceiling(day(hoje)/7) # retorna a semana do mês a qual a data está
[1] 2
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Eu havia confundido a quantidade de semanas no mês, mas já corrigi a pergunta.